# How to use Delta Lake with spark-shell?

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I'm trying to write as Spark DF as a DeltaTable. **It's working fine in my IDE Intelliji** , But with the same dependencies and versions it's not working in my spark REPL(Spark shell)

Spark Version :2.4.0
Scala Version :2.11.8

Dependencies in Intelliji (Dependencies for whole project , Kindly ignore relevant)

```
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.8'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.8'
    compile 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.1.2'
    compile 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-swing_2.11:2.0.3'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-graphx_2.11:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.11:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.4.0'
    compile group: 'io.delta', name: 'delta-core_2.11', version: '0.5.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.8.2'
    compile 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.2'
    compile 'org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:1.8.2'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.15'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.26'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.scalatest', name: 'scalatest_2.12', version: '3.2.0-SNAP10'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail' ,name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.0'
    compile 'com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11'
    compile 'com.hortonworks:shc:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-client', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-server', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-common', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase', version: '1.2.5', ext: 'pom'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-protocol', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-hadoop2-compat', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-annotations', version: '1.2.5'

    // jackson modues
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-core-asl', version: '1.9.13'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.9.13'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.7'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-scala_2.11', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-jaxb-annotations', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'org.json4s', name: 'json4s-jackson_2.11', version: '3.2.10'
    compile group: 'com.twitter', name: 'parquet-jackson', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-jaxrs', version: '1.9.13'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-xc', version: '1.9.13'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-paranamer', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: '2.7.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-client', version: '2.7.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-hdfs', version: '2.7.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-core', version: '2.7.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-annotations', version: '2.7.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-auth', version: '2.7.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-yarn-common', version: '2.7.3'
```

Piece of code which i'm trying to execute

```
import io.delta._

val dF=spark.read.load("path") //parquet file
dF.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("topic","partition","key").save("path") // delta table
```

spark-shell Command used:

```
spark-shell --packages com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.6,com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.0,org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13,org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13,com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.7,com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.8.6,com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:2.8.6,com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.8.6,com.twitter:parquet-jackson:1.6.0,org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.9.13,org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:1.9.13,com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:2.8.6,io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.5.0,commons-io:commons-io:2.5
```

Error in REPL:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse$default$3()Z
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType$.fromJson(DataType.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.Metadata$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(actions.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.Metadata$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(actions.scala:201)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.Metadata.schema$lzycompute(actions.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.Metadata.schema(actions.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.schema.ImplicitMetadataOperation$class.updateMetadata(ImplicitMetadataOperation.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.updateMetadata(WriteIntoDelta.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.write(WriteIntoDelta.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WriteIntoDelta.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WriteIntoDelta.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.run(WriteIntoDelta.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
    at org.controller.deltaLakeEG.deltaLakeHadoopEg$.main(deltaLakeHadoopEg.scala:29)
    at org.controller.deltaLakeEG.deltaLakeHadoopEg.main(deltaLakeHadoopEg.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 6):

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#id1):

> Delta Lake requires Apache Spark version 2.4.2 or above

Please upgrade your Spark version to at least 2.4.2 in IntelliJ IDEA (or issues show up). The latest version as of this writing is 3.1.1, but that's not supported [yet](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/594#issuecomment-814501913) (April, 7th):

> We have upgraded Spark to 3.1.1 in master branch. We are still working on some items before doing a release.

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#spark-scala-shell):

> Run spark-shell with the Delta Lake package:
>
> `bin/spark-shell --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.8.0`

From myself, use `--conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension` to enable Delta Lake's SQL commands, e.g. `DESCRIBE DETAIL`, `GENERATE`.

The entire command to run `spark-shell` with Delta Lake 0.8.0 should be as follows:

```
./bin/spark-shell \
  --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0 \
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension \
  --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
```

Comment: Found the issue, Not able to write a DF as a parquet file. with smae dependencies and spak version, any idea why?

Comment: Please start over with the "purest" spark-shell possible, i.e. start it with the `--packages` for the `delta-core` only. Else I think you should ask a separate question.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski : please check this once, unable to work with fat jar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166804/delta-lake-integartion-with-spark-2-4-4

Answer (score 1):

```
bin/spark-shell --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1

import io.delta.tables._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath("/tmp/delta-table")
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark itself has a dependency on Jackson, and the version you're instructing spark-shell to use is incompatible. Per https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/pom.xml, 2.4.0 uses Jackson 2.6.7. Is there a particular reason that you need Jackson 2.10 in this case?

Comment: I added 2.10 due to Hbase integration. So should i use 2.6.7 jackson instead of 2.10?

Comment: Removed those dependencies and ran , still same issue. ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse$default$3()Z```

Comment: Tried with all version of 2_11 json4s in this page .https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-core_2.11

Answer (score 0):

Please check here: https://docs.delta.io/0.8.0/quick-start.html

To run the spark-shell use the command

```
spark-shell --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0 --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```